# Django: What is the best way to manage manytomany field in django form?

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am a total begineer at django. As a matter of fact, I have just gotten into coding and currently i am working for a library management system for my college. I have a model named book which has a field author which is a many to many field. When I used that model class in model field, django by default creates a multipleselectfield for my many to many relation which solves the problem but is not the best option if we weigh in the user experience's factor. What are the other widgets or field that i can use to make it more convenient to the users?